# Alterar um elemento com jquery

Tags: jquery

Tenho uma lista de itens e cada item dessa lista é um link com um monte de atributos e itens dentro desse link.

resumindo meu link esta assim:

```
<a href="#" class="editItem list-group-item" data-id="1001" data-validate="2014-09-08">
    <h4>Meu Item</h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</a>
```

O que estou fazendo é que eu clico nesse item, dai abre um modal que tem um formulário que o usuário preenche esse formulário e ao salvar eu devo atualizar esse item, mas lembrando que tenho que alterar o `<a>` inteiro, pois pode ter atributos dele que alteram e os textos também.
Eu já fiz toda a parte do ajax, esta enviando certo, só não estou conseguindo substituir mesmo.

Tentei algo como

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : 'pagina.php',
    data : dados,
    success : function ( html ) {
        var itens = $("a.editItem");
        $.each(itens, function(i, item) {
            // item_id é uma variavel que tenho que da o item clicado
            if ( $(item).data('id') == item_id ) {

                // AQUI ESTA O MEU PROBLEMA
                $(item).before(html);
                $(item).remove();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: E o que recebe do ajax? HTML com um novo elemento? o `data-id` do elemento?

Comment: o retorno do ajax é o html com o item `<a href="#" class="editItem list-group-item" data-id="1001" data-validate="2014-09-08">
        <h4>Meu Item</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </a>`
mas esse item pode ter a data-validate diferente e os textos também, já o data-id é o mesmo

Comment: E esse elemento que recebe do ajax deve subtituir o clicado certo?

Comment: isso mesmo, eu pensei em remover o item clicado e depois colocar o retorno no lugar, pois tenho outros items e com isso o usuário sabe o que ele alterou e só continua a lista

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para substituir elementos com jQuery pode usar o [.replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/). O sintaxe é

```
$(elementosOriginais).replaceWidth(<novo conteudo>);
```

Assim na função onde escuta o clic pode fazer:

```
$("a.editItem").on('click', function(){

    var este = this;

    // chamar o ajax
    // etc...
    success : function (html) {
        $(este).replaceWith(html);
```

E assim o elemento clicado vai ser substituido pelo novo vindo do ajax.
É importante fazer `var este = this;` antes do ajax, pois o `this` dentro do ajax não se refere ao elemento clicado;

Atenção que este método remove todos os event handlers associados ao elemento removido. Aí sugiro delegar o oscultador de evento para algo do tipo:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.editItem', function(){
```

---

Edit: pelo comentário que deixou em baixo percebo que nõ pode dar o passo `var este = this;`. Seria interessante vêr o código para perceber como o ajax é chamado. De qualquer maneira pode ir buscar o `data-id` do elemento que o ajax retorna e usar esse `data-id` para encontrar o link que quer remover.

#### Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/Sergio_fiddle/b481ozrk/

```
success: function (html) {
    var este = $('a[data-id="' + $(html).data('id') + '"]');
    este.replaceWith(html);
```

Comment: Ainda continua removendo o item, e não tenho como guardar o `this` na variavel `este` como no exemplo, pois quando o usuário clica para salvar o item no modal dai vai rolar o ajax de salvar no banco em uma outra função em outro arquivo e para fazer esse update esta sendo em outra função também. Parece um pouco confuso, mas com isso estou usando essas funções em muitas outras partes do sistema

Comment: @MarceloDiniz o elemento que vem do ajax tem o mesmo data-id que o elemento clicado? esse data-id deve ser unico?

Comment: isso mesmo, tenho vários items, cada um tem um id unico

Comment: eu até tentei colocar essa variavel `este` para teste, mas como esta fora do escopo da função ele nem encontra.

Comment: @MarceloDiniz fiz update na resposta

Comment: Então @Sergio, entendi o q fez mas ainda assim não deu certo. Mas só para constar, eu fiz um teste assim `$(item).replaceWith( "<a href='#' class=''>teste</a>" );` e dai ele colocou esse link com o teste no lugar. O que vejo é que por ter o mesmo data-id dai não esta dando certo. Agora estou pensando em uma solução.

Comment: @MarceloDiniz Pode fazer `console.log(html);` no sucess do ajax?

Comment: @MarceloDiniz dê uma a este exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/Sergio_fiddle/b481ozrk/

Comment: não há mais necessidade de eu mostrar o retorno, pois quando fui para fazer isso percebi que no final do retorno tinha um erro e por isso ele parava a execução. Mas ainda assim muito obrigado por tudo mesmo. Ajuda muito.

Answer (score 1):

Na versão 1.9 do jQuery você pode tentar usar o .replaceWith().

O uso, no seu caso, seria algo do tipo:

```
$(item).replaceWith(html);
```

Agora, fique esperto porque o novo `<a>` inserido não tem o callback registrado, o que significa que se você clicar nesse novo `<a>` posteriormente, ele não vai chamar a função que abre a janela modal que você citou anteriormente.

Comment: Foi essa minha primeira tentativa e não funcionou. Só para constar, estou usando 1.10.2, e também será outro problema se não tiver como abrir o modal clicando nesse item, bem observado!!!

Comment: O que não funcionou? O item exibido em tela foi atualizado para o que veio do servidor ou não? Tenho que saber disso pra ir meio que no passo a passo...